# Python Multiprocessing Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am learning about python's multiprocessing module. I want to make my code use all my CPU resources. This is the code I wrote:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def work():
   for i in range(1000):
      x=5
      y=10
      z=x+y

if __name__ == '__main__':
   start1 = time.time()
   for i in range(100):
      p=Process(target=work)
      p.start()
      p.join()
   end1=time.time()
   start = time.time()
   for i in range(100):
      work()
   end=time.time()
   print(f'With Parallel {end1-start1}')
   print(f'Without Parallel {end-start}')
```

The output I get is this:

```
 With Parallel 0.8802454471588135
 Without Parallel 0.00039649009704589844
```

I tried experimenting with different range values in the for loops or using print statement only in work function but everytime without parallel runs faster. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the `work()` function is too simple to be representative. In your case you just have a case when there's an overhead caused by instantiation of `Process` objects and their functioning

Comment: any feedback, please?

Answer (score 3):

Your benchmark method is problematic:

```
for i in range(100):
    p = Process(target=work)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I guess you want to run 100 processes in parallel, but `Process.join()` [blocks until process exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join), you effectively run in serial. Besides, run more busy processes than CPU cores count leads to high CPU contention which is a performance penalty. And as a comment pointed out, your `work()` function is too simple, compare to the overhead of `Process` creation.

A better version:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def work():
    for i in range(2000000):
        pow(i, 10)

n_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # 8
total_runs = n_processes * 4
ps = []
n = total_runs

start1 = time.time()
while n:
    # ensure processes number limit
    ps = [p for p in ps if p.is_alive()]
    if len(ps) < n_processes:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=work)
        p.start()
        ps.append(p)
        n = n-1
    else:
        time.sleep(0.01)
# wait for all processes to finish
while any(p.is_alive() for p in ps):
    time.sleep(0.01)
end1=time.time()

start = time.time()
for i in range(total_runs):
    work()
end=time.time()

print(f'With Parallel {end1-start1:.4f}s')
print(f'Without Parallel {end-start:.4f}s')
print(f'Acceleration factor {(end-start)/(end1-start1):.2f}')
```

result:

```
With Parallel 4.2835s
Without Parallel 33.0244s
Acceleration factor 7.71
```